# Unable to communicate through winexe from centos 7 to windows server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I am trying to communicate the windows server 2016 from `centos7` using `winexe` but i am getting the following error

Sample command:

```
[root]# winexe --user=Administrator --password='******'  //192.168.5.2 "ipconfig /all"
```

> [winexe/winexe.c:129:on_ctrl_pipe_error()] ERROR: Cannot open control
>   pipe - NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER

It's working on `2012r2` version and older versions but its giving issues when i tried on `2016`, can any provide solution for this thanks in advance

Comment: winexe install a service, which is logged on the target machine. What does your log (application eventlog in this case) say?